# Using boost::asio to listen to two socket

Tags: c++, boost-asio

How can I listen to two socket simultaneously using boost::asio? I think there shouldn't be two `io_service`. Should I resolve two queries for two acceptors to listen to two sokets? Supposed the two sockets are:

```
127.0.0.1:7001
127.0.0.2:7001
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in using one asio `io_service`. (You are of course allowed to use as many as you would like, but it's more efficient to just use one since it blocks in a thread and you avoid unnecessary context switching. Also, you can call `io_service::run` from multiple threads should you wish to use multiple processors.)

Encapsulate the `acceptor` and the `socket` in a class as is demonstrated in many asio examples, and pass the io_service to the class constructor by reference. You can then `bind` the acceptor to the desired address, `listen` and call `async_accept` in a class method that you call.